# Create HTML Link to Call Button Click Event on Different Page

Tags: html, css

Per the code below, I'm able to create a Link with parameters that will navigate to my desired target page:

```
<style>
    .fancy-link{
        color: #FFFFFF;  
        text-decoration: none;  
        transition: all 0.3s linear;  
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;  
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
        border-radius: 4px; 
        border: 1px solid black; 
        background: #0080FF;  
        padding-top: 0px;  
        padding-left: 5px; 
        padding-right: 5px; 
        padding-bottom: 0px; 
        width: 100px;  
        height: 10px; 
        font-size: 15px; 
        font-weight: bold;} 

  .fancy-link:hover{ 
        color: #F44336;   
        padding-left: 10px;}
</style>

<html>
<a class="fancy-link" name="View" id="View"
  href="'||'https://XXXXXX-sb1.app.website.com/app/common/custom/custrecordentry.nl?
  rectype=142&id='||{internalid}||'"target="_blank">Check-In</a>
</html>
```

While this is useful, my intended goal is for this link to actually call the following button click event/element that lives @ at the desired url (see href above), without actually navigating to that page. Is this possible? If so, some code examples would be very helpful.

```
 .<input type="button" style="" class="rndbuttoninpt bntBgT"value="Check-In" id="custpageworkflow157" name="custpageworkflow157"onclick="try{
    if (!!window) {
        var origScriptIdForLogging = window.NLScriptIdForLogging;
        var origDeploymentIdForLogging = window.NLDeploymentIdForLogging;
        window.NLScriptIdForLogging ='CUSTOMSCRIPT_STICK_USER_PREFERENCE';
        window.NLDeploymentIdForLogging= 'CUSTOMDEPLOY_STICK_USER_PREFERENCE';
    }
    try{
        NS.Workflow.buttonClick('custpageworkflow157');
    }
    catch(e){
        document.location = addParamToURL(addParamToURL(addParamToURL(document.location.href,'workflowbutton','157'),'workflowbuttoninstanceid','84083'),'workflowbuttonobsoletehandling','T');
    }
}
finally{
    if (!!window) {
        window.NLScriptIdForLogging = origScriptIdForLogging;
        window.NLDeploymentIdForLogging = origDeploymentIdForLogging;
    }
}
;
return false;
"onmousedown="this.setAttribute('_mousedown','T');
setButtonDown(true, false, this);
" onmouseup="this.setAttribute('_mousedown','F');
setButtonDown(false, false, this);
" onmouseout="if(this.getAttribute('_mousedown')=='T') setButtonDown(false,false, this);
" onmouseover="if(this.getAttribute('_mousedown')=='T') setButtonDown(true, false, this);
" _mousedown="F">
```

Comment: So you want to click in a button on another page without navigating to it, I don't know if it's possible but can I ask why this approach? can't you simply submit the request directly from the first page to the action that you want to be submitted on the second one?

Comment: Hi Edu. No, that's not possible as this is a results column formula that's injecting the code (hack) - creating a link/button for each row; it needs to be inline with string literals.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get away with this with a simple event listener in the button you are creating:

```
document.getElementById('custpageworkflow157).click();
```

So basically something like this:

```
document.getElementById("View").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById('custpageworkflow157).click();
});
```

Comment: this is getting injected inline, so it needs to be a string literal, which gets confusing.I added the following; however, it appears to be ignoring the script code; I can execute an alert() inside the script tag without issue: `'<html><script>document.getElementById("View").addEventListener("click", function(){document.getElementById("custpageworkflow157").click();</script><a class="fancy-link" name="View" id="View" href="https://XXXXX-sb1.app.website.com/app/common/custom/custrecordentry.nl?rectype=142&id='||{internalid}||'"target="_blank">Check-In</a></html>'`

Comment: What am I missing?